# Variável não altera no nodeJS

Tags: node.js, express.js, navegador-de-internet, http-request, cors

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em Node para comunicação de guaritas (API) e estou com problema para alterar o valor de uma variável. segue abaixo o código:

```js
var net     = require("net");
var express = require('express');
var http    = require('http');
var cors    = require('cors');

var app         = express();
var server      = http.createServer(app);
var bodyParser  = require('body-parser');

app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser({limit: '500mb'}));

server.listen(8080, function(){  
  console.log('\nlistening on *:8080');
});


var client = net.createConnection(/*ip da aplicação*/);

client.on("connect", function(data){
    console.log(`linear conectado porta: 9001`);
});

client.on("data", function(data){
    var hex = data.toString(`hex`);
    console.log(data);
    console.log('recebe dados: ' +hex+'\n-- end --\n');
});

client.on("end", function(data){
    console.log(`end: `);
    console.log(data);
});

app.get("/teste", (req, res) => {

    var acao                = req.query.acao;

    //http://easyonlineconverter.com/converters/checksum_converter.html
    //https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html

    var data_hora       = [0x00, 0x0C];
    var id              = [0x00, 0x03];
    var dispositivos    = [0x00, 0x46];
    var lbl_veiculos    = [0x00, 0x1A];

    var reiniciar       = [0x00, 0x12];
    var atualizar       = [0x00, 0x1D];

    // terimnar alterar data 
    var alterar_data    = [0x00, 0x0B, 30, 12, 2033, 12, 16, 11];


    switch(acao){

        case 'data_hora':
        var bytes = data_hora;
        break;

        case 'id':
        var bytes = id;
        break;

        case 'dispositivos':
        var bytes = dispositivos;
        break;

        case 'lbl_veiculos':
        var bytes = lbl_veiculos;
        break;

        case 'atualizar':
        var bytes = atualizar;
        break;

        case 'reiniciar':
        var bytes = reiniciar;
        break;

        case 'alterar_data':
        var bytes = alterar_data;
        break;

    }   

    checksum = 0;
    var checksum = bytes.reduce((x, y) => x + y);
    bytes.push(checksum);

    var buffer = new Buffer.from(bytes);
    console.log('\nwrite sent: ' + bytes,'\n');
    client.write(buffer);

    res.send("OK");



});
```

Para fazer o teste eu chamo o localhost no browser com o comando como querystring.  EX:
`- http://localhost:8080/teste?acao=alterar_data -> chama função alterar data`

Meu problema é que ao executar a primeira vez com o node a operação **alterar_data** ele faz tudo certo, mas se eu tento alterar a variável ele age como se eu não tivesse feito modificações, e só volta a agir normalmente (enviando as alterações) quando eu encerro a aplicação node e inicio novamente, segue os print's:

-Primeira alteração (comportamento esperado):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

-Segunda alteração (alterado o conteúdo da variável, contudo a resposta é a mesma):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

-Terceira alteração (reiniciada a aplicação node usando code runner. o valor da variável se apresenta como reescrita):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe por que é necessário reiniciar o node para essa variável se apresentar como reescrita? Existe uma maneira de eu contornar essa situação sem ter que ficar encerrando minha aplicação?

Answer (score 0):

Foi erro meu e não comportamento atípico do node, estava rodando o código pelo code runner e não através do nodemon.

Se alguém mais tiver problemas similares com o node, é necessário utilizar o nodemon:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon